# iPhone web app - type=text inner shadow issue

Tags: iphone, css, mobile-webkit

I am trying to disable top inner shadow in input=text field which is applied by default by iPhone. Any ideas how to do this? tried to overwrite -webkit-box-shadow with no success.

[alt text http://feedsmanagement.com/example.png](http://feedsmanagement.com/example.png)

cheers

Comment: Thanks for posting, also had the same issue.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Have you tried using `-webkit-appearance: none` then applying a custom border like `border: 1px solid black;`

I can't try this out at this moment.

Comment: It's not recommended to use that technique because of this [issue](http://zomigi.com/blog/bug-fixes-for-removing-the-inner-shadow-on-ios-inputs/). Richard Rose's answer is the best way to achieve the solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can add a background image gradient to remove the inner shadow;
background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, 
        from(rgb(255,255,255)),
        to(rgb(255,255,255)));

Comment: This is the best answer that doesn't interfere with any other styling. For example, the -webkit-appearance:caret; will mess up most other styles that you may have assigned already.

Comment: This one only removes what was asked (shadow), instead of changing the style completely, "appearance: caret" for example does not let you use borders...

Answer (score 2):

I have had this same issue, wanting to display input text fields that are styled: WITHOUT shadows. My solution (works perfectly on iPad/ iPhone) make background gif that is completely transparent. Apply that style to your input field. My code was:

.textBox input {
    border:none;
    background:url(../images/bg_inputFix.gif);
  }

-Jamin

Answer (score 2):

I found that Jamin's answer was better for now.  If I use the `-webkit-appearance: none` method instead, on the iPad it no longer applies my focus (pseudo-class) styles when a textarea/input is selected. It kind of ruins my form styling because textareas/inputs not in focus are significantly subdued.

Comment: And the reason I didn't comment on Jamin's post or vote it up is because I don't have any "reputation" yet!  :\

Answer (score 2):

I did the background gradient and it doesnt work, I also found a variation of it:

```
input[type='text']{
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(hsla(0,0%,100%,0)), to(hsla(0,0%,100%,0)));
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,100%,0), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
}
```

and that hasn't worked either :(

Answer (score 0):

```
-webkit-appearance:caret;
```

Should remove just the inset shadows on your inputs